How to schedule and stop local notifications on a specific date in Flutter using flutter_local_notifications?
I'm trying to schedule daily local notifications in my Flutter app. The notifications should start on October 10, 2024 (It's today date), and automatically stop on November 15, 2024.
I want the notifications to be shown daily at a specific time until the stop date. I have successfully set up daily notifications, but I'm not sure how to stop them automatically after the end date.
How can I configure the notification to automatically stop after a specific date in Flutter using the flutter_local_notifications package?
Future<void> scheduleDailyNotification(int id, String title, String body, DateTime dateTime) async {
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      _nextInstanceOfTime(dateTime),
      medicationNotificationDetails(),
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }


 tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTime(DateTime dateTime) {
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
    var location = tz.getLocation(tz.local.currentTimeZone.abbreviation);
    tz.setLocalLocation(location);
    var scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime.from(dateTime, location);
    return scheduledDate;
  }



I'm not a flutter local notification expert, but it seems to me that this code just schedules one specific notification on _nextInstanceOfTime(dateTime). So I assume you're executing this code multiple times to get the daily reminders. If so, you should stop calling it once _nextInstanceOfTime(dateTime) is after your end date/time (Nov 15).

Yes, in general it is not a bad idea to do it through loop but local notification has a limitation for iOS and we can register a maximum of 64 notifications and if we do it through loop in my case I can exceed this number. At the moment the code is called once and is repeated every time at the same time by matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time. @FrankvanPuffelen

Create your notification as usual and add the end date in the payload.
Check the end date in onNotificationDisplayedMethod listener and delete the notification if the date is passed
Here an example, I used AwesomeNotifications but the logic is the same.
You can also have a function in your main to check and cleanup your "old" notifications.
static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayed(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
  if (receivedNotification.payload != null && receivedNotification.payload!.containsKey('endDate')) {
    final DateTime endDate = DateTime.parse(receivedNotification.payload!['endDate']!);
    if (endDate.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
      await AwesomeNotifications().cancel(receivedNotification.id!);
    }
  }

  // Handle notification display
  print('Notification displayed: ${receivedNotification.id}');
}

But be careful, you can’t clean the old notifications if the app is not open or in the background. Thus, a notification can still be triggered even after the end date.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
